# Not getting a confirmation email in Paypal sandbox

Tags: email, paypal

I have set up several buyer account in the sandbox and made purchases through my website. The purchases are "pending" because the test account email aren't confirmed through Paypal.
I've gone to my test account Notifications but there doesn't seem to be a way to confirm these accounts. All I get are emails like this:

### We're sending you a new PayPal payment card

Hello Paula Hatchling,

We're sending you a new PayPal payment card. We'll mail it to: 1 Main StSan Jose, CA 95131US
When it arrives, you'll need to activate it:
- Log in to PayPal and go to your Settings.
- Click Payment preferences, then click Update under "In-store checkout."
- Click Activate under "Payment card."

After that, you can use your PayPal payment card in participating retail stores to pay with your balance - or any bank account or credit card linked to your PayPal account.

---

Help: 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/helpweb?cmd=_help
Security Center: 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/security

Please don't reply to this email. It'll just confuse the computer that sent it and you won't get a response.

Copyright © 2015 PayPal, Inc. All rights reserved. PayPal is located at 2211 N. First St., San Jose, CA 95131.

PayPal Email ID  PP1711 - f9455a693c000

---

How can I confirm these accounts?

Thanks,
Ann

Answer (score 12):

Emails in the sandbox don't actually send to any real email address.  They all get sent to the Notifications section of the account within your developer account.

Login to http://developer.paypal.com, go to your list of sandbox accounts, and find the little notifications link under each individual sandbox account.  That is basically your inbox for that sandbox account.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. But I thought there would be a way to "confirm" the account so that my sandbox purchase would be approved and I could see the full transaction on my website. Right now my transactions are "pending" confirmation of the sandbox accounts.

Comment: Sandbox accounts are automatically verified and confirmed when you create them.  If you're getting pending transactions you must have something else going on.  What currency codes / country codes are you working with?

Comment: Thank you very much! They (Paypal) supposed to put this notice!

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer here. 
Update as of 2022 - the notifications can be found here: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications
Or via the three dots next to each sandbox account, and then 'View notifications'.

Comment: (in 2022) You also need to connect test account to the sandbox to see the notifications
[https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts) :
 To link other accounts created in sandbox to your developer account, _authenticate with the credentials of the test account you want to link_

Answer (score 0):

For other developers who may face this issue. You need to login to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com then click on `Profile settings` (top right) and under `Login and security`, click `Update Email`.

In the next page, you'll see a list of email(s) which you can confirm by clicking on `Edit` and then `Confirm this email`. Once you've done that, go back to your developer account and check out the `Notifications` section at https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications

You'll see a notification with subject `Activate Your PayPal Account.`